# Assigning Text to Random Buttons

Tags: vb.net, button, random

I have four buttons. The idea is that I read 4 lines (individual words) and assign them each to a button. The program is a multiple choice question/answer where one button holds the correct answer and the other three hold wrong answers. I want to know how I would assign the four words to a random button (Buttons 2, 3, 4, 5) so that the 'correct' button is not one button specifically.

For example...

```
Dim word1, word2, word3, word4 as string
word1="Hello"
word2="World"
word3="This"
word4="Computer"
Dim answer as String = word2
```

How would I go about assigning these variables, `word1`, `word2`, `word3`, and `word4` to four different buttons, assumed to be named `Button2`, `Button3`, `Button4`, and `Button5`?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to put your words into a list and random sort it first.

```
Imports System.Linq



Dim Words As List(Of String) = {"Hello", "World", "How's", "Things"}.ToList
    Words.Sort(Function(X As String, Y As String)
                   Return Rnd().CompareTo(CSng(0.5))
               End Function)
    Button2.Text = Words(0)
    Button3.Text = Words(1)
    Button4.Text = Words(2)
    Button5.Text = Words(3)
```

Or if you prefer the short form,

```
    Dim Words As List(Of String) = {"Hello", "World", "How's", "Things"}.ToList
    Words.Sort(Function(X, Y) Rnd().CompareTo(CSng(0.5)))
    Button2.Text = Words(0)
    Button3.Text = Words(1)
    Button4.Text = Words(2)
    Button5.Text = Words(3)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well! My list of words is currently over 50 words, and it gives me 3 random choices and one correct one, and usually are very different. I've had the same question repeat, but the button on which the correct answer was changed.

Comment: Cool, don't forget to accept the answer then. You may also want to add a Randomize() statement in there somewhere too to make it more random. But I doubt it will matter for this application.